# How to stop the SurfaceView in Android?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

Recently when writing a game I experienced a problem. In my game I used `SurfaceView` and I used the `while(true)` as the condition. After I press the home button, the program quits and I see the log. But I find the loop  `While(true)`  is still running. Why is the loop still running after the Activity has stopped? Could anybody help and tell me the reason. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this in the game I'm working on now:

```
    //Makes the thread draw until the state of running is set to false
    while(this.running)
    {
            //Draw
    }
    this.thread.interrupt();
```

In onPause:

```
//Stop the thread that is responible for the drawing.
this.worker.running = false;
```

In onResume:

```
//Creates a new thread instance which sets this.running to true and calls the drawing method again
this.worker.restart();
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution might be to set a bool to hold the state of the application and then set that to false when the game quits.

```
while(appActive)
    //do game logic
```

***EDIT**: Thanks to Braj and Fildor for feedback*

in the onPause() event handler add a line

```
appActive = false;
```

((NOTE: I've not done any Android development, this is purely a theoretical response))

Comment: Though it's correct. Do it in onPause(), because this is the only callback, that's guaranteed to be called.

Comment: I work the other way but thanks for you theoretical response,+1